# How to make this auto-filling text and logo animation?

Tags: after-effects, animation, color

I found this great video on youtube:

and I just love this text animation at the beginning.
I mean that one which start like black and auto filling itself with white color and the animation also repeats with the logo and with other text but it changes the color to red.

*I've tried using stroke effects, but I couldn't figure out how this can be achieved.*

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a proof of concept. Steps to reproduce:

- on a new comp, create a shape object filled with black color;
- animate some properties, in this case, I'm changing the Inner Radius;
- duplicate this shape layer and move it a few frames ahead in the timeline (so it's out of sync with the layer below);
- change its color to white and activate the [Track Matte](https://video.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bafter-effects%5D%20track%20matte) pointing to the first layer as `Parent`;

This is the result (showing all the frames at once):

[image: resulting animation]

And this is the base composition:

[image: animation timeline]

Comment: Hello brasofilo ! Sorry for long not answearing your response but i have a lot of work to do and i just now finally find time to test it and answer!
You are great man! I just do it and it's great! Didn't expect that it's so simple..
Thank you very much again! That is what i was looking for! 
Thaaaaaaaaaank you!
:)))))))))))

Comment: Glad to hear, Raznyy, have fun :)